# Error when trying to import GameViewController

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, importerror

I'm making an app with Swift and SpriteKit, and when I try to import GameViewController says that "No such module 'GameViewController'".

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use import between swift files in a project. Just use the `GameViewController class` inside the other swift classes.